# Stirling Numbers $ \sum_{j= m}^{n-r} \binom{n}j {j \brace m} {n-j\brace r} = \binom{m} {m+r} {n\brace m+r} $ Combinatorical Proof or Algebraic

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

$$\sum_{j= m}^{n-r} \binom{j}n {j \brace m} {n-j\brace r} = \binom{m} {m+r} {n\brace m+r}$$

I am trying to proof some identies from concrete mathmatics page 265. But i cant get nowhere. No clues where to start, I have found a proof involving Euler's Formula for Stirling Number. The Books gives them: Like here there are not event a hint how to show it. 
update: 
Well there is a clue in other book: both sides counting pair $(P_1,P_2)$ with $P_1 (k+r)$ partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ $P_2$ subfamily of $k$-blocks of $P_1,\ldots$ what ever this means

Comment: well index error fixed! Now it makes sense :)

Comment: Are you sure of $m\choose m+r$ for $r>-1$????

Comment: And are you sure $j\choose n$? Check the whole expression and modify it for helping you.

Comment: Appears to hold with the binomial coefficient arguments exchanged.

Comment: I started to typeset a proof when I noticed that this identity appeared here at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477859) some months ago last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This combinatorial Identity represents a bicolouring of a partition
\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{red}{(r_{1,1} \cdots ) (r_{2,1} \cdots )\cdots (r_{m,1}\cdots) } \color{blue}{(b_{1,1} \cdots ) (b_{2,1} \cdots )\cdots (b_{r,1}\cdots) }
\end{eqnarray*}
where the red partiton is of $k$ elemnets into $m$ blocks & the blue partition of $n-k$ elements into $r$ blocks.

Partition $[n]$ into $k+r$ blocks then colour $k$ of the blocks red and $n-k$ of them blue.

Choose $n-j$ elements from $[n]$, colour them red and partition them into $m$ blocks. Now colour the other $j$ elements blue and partition them into $r$ blocks. Thus
\begin{eqnarray*}
{{n}\brace r+m}\dbinom{r+m}{m}=\sum_{j =m}^{n-r}{{j}\brace r}{{n-j}\brace m}\dbinom{n}{j}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: wow! This is a very nice interpretation